# Converting multi-language function

Tags: php

This is my first ask here so don't judge me if i posted it wrong.

I have this function for my multi-lang support

```
<?
header('Cache-control: private'); // IE 6 FIX
if(isSet($_GET['lang']))
{
    $lang = $_GET['lang'];
    // register the session and set the cookie
    $_SESSION['lang'] = $lang;
    setcookie('lang', $lang, time() + (3600 * 24 * 30));
}
else if(isSet($_SESSION['lang']))
{
    $lang = $_SESSION['lang'];
}
else if(isSet($_COOKIE['lang']))
{
    $lang = $_COOKIE['lang'];
}
else
{
    $lang = 'en';
}
switch ($lang) {
    case 'bg':
    $lang_file = 'bg.php';
    break;
    default:
    $lang_file = 'en.php';
}
define('IN_VALID',true);
include_once '_src/lang/'.$lang_file;
?>
```

It gets languages by &lang=en or &lang=bg .

How i can convert it to get &lang:en instead of &lang=en (if it's possible)

Comment: Please indent your code properly

Comment: You can do it with url rewrite, if you know how to use it

Answer (score 0):

`?key1=value1&key2=value2` is standard `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` format.

To use your format, you should parse it on your own, route that I don't advise.

Comment: Uby u gave me good idea I've managed it with `RewriteRule ^lang:(.*)$ index.php?lang=$1 [NE,L]` Now i have to do 2nd step becouse i use `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?p=%{REQUEST_URI}&%{QUERY_STRING} [NE,L]` for getting pages i need to write RewriteRule to get example.com/page/setlang:en

Answer (score 0):

You can check for `isset($_GET["lang:en"])`.

But this is not to advice. `=` is the standard separator for keys and values. There's no need to change it.